# pdf attachment with @sendgrid/mail

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, pdfkit

I want to attach pdf file in nodejs. I am using @sendgrid/mail for mail sending and pdfkit for creating pdf file. I have created pdf file with HTML data and added company logo. This attachment is received successfully in my inbox. But company logo in pdf attachment is not showing there. Here is my code,

```
let invoice_template_content = "html data";
let doc = new PDFDocument;
var config = { format: 'A4' };
let filename = "attachment.pdf";
let pathToAttachment = `path/to/my/folder/attachment/${filename}`;
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(pathToAttachment));
doc.end();

pdf.create(invoice_template_content, config).toFile(pathToAttachment, function(err, res) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  let attachment = fs.readFileSync(pathToAttachment).toString("base64");
  let msg = {
    from: fromMail,
    to: body.to_email,
    subject: subject,
    html: "Please find attachment",
    attachments: [{
      content: attachment,
      filename: filename,
      type: "application/pdf",
      disposition: "attachment"
    }]
  };
  sgMail.send(msg).then(success => {
    console.log("message sent");
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  });
});
```

Comment: How are you trying to set the company logo? The issue will lie in your PDF generation, not in the email sending part.

Comment: I have set company logo like this

Comment: Https://www.example.com/logo.png

Comment: Not sure what you mean there, that is just a URL. How are you placing the logo in your PDF document?

Comment: <img src='https://www.domain-name.com/logo.png'/>

Comment: If you just load the HTML that you are using to render the PDF document in a browser, does it work and does the logo show?

Comment: Yes, it's working with html content

Comment: Are you using PDFKit? Or [node-html-pdf](https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf)? It doesn't look like PDFKit supports rendering HTML as PDF.